# mysql script. SET request doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that looks simple, but for some reason I cant fix it. May be you can solve it in one look. 
I have the following script. It calls no mistakes but doesnt work correctly.  I divided the SET request on two to better explanation of the problem. I also added some comments to better look. The point is that one of the two similar requests doesnt work...

```
include_once ("../php/db_connects.php"); // connect to the database
$query = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE status = "1"'); //pick all the lines with status (enum) = 1;
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($query); // general staff
do {
$pluses = $row ['pluses'];
$minuses = $row['minuses'];
$link = $row['link'];

$count = $pluses-$minuses; // checking if article has more positive votes than negaitve
if($count > 0){
mysql_query ('UPDATE articles SET rating = 100 WHERE link = "$link"', $db_conx);
//the first request works (rating is Int)
mysql_query ('UPDATE articles SET status = "2" WHERE link = "$link"', $db_conx);
//the second request doesnt show any mistakes, but it doesn't change status on "2". status is Enum. (ps. there is value of "2" in the database)
}
echo "link = " . $link . " count = " . $count;
}while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query));
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you get no errors, then find out value of `$link` and run the query from MySQL GUI and find out what's wrong. Also, asking for help, pasting code and saying something doesn't work without giving us the values of your variables or without checking query return values (succeeded or not) turns possible answers into guessing what might be wrong.

Comment: the $link is fine, I can echo everything and the first SET is working fine, so the $link is good

Comment: what do the calls of ```mysql_query ( "UPDATE...``` return?

Comment: it returns nothing like if the code is working

Comment: if it returns actually nothing (i mean, `echo mysql_query(...)` appears blank on screen it means that it has returned `false` which means that there's an error

Comment: Then if the `$link` is fine, it must be that you have gremlins in your  pc and you can't be helped the regular way. I often wonder why are people so reluctant to TRY their queries from within a GUI. You'd note that you use double quotes where they don't belong.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and your code may misbehave if you have `"` and/or `'` in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must change this:

```
mysql_query ('UPDATE articles SET rating = 100 WHERE link = "$link"', $db_conx);
//the first request works (rating is Int)
mysql_query ('UPDATE articles SET status = "2" WHERE link = "$link"', $db_conx);
```

to this:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE articles SET rating = 100 WHERE link = '$link'", $db_conx);
//the first request works (rating is Int)
mysql_query ("UPDATE articles SET status = '2' WHERE link = '$link'", $db_conx);
```

The reason is that PHP will not replace the variables in single quotes strings.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! I can bet Ive tried changing "" and ''... omg, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: you can always upvote...